# How to run an iterative cross-correlation within a 3D array?

Tags: python, matlab, for-loop, multidimensional-array, cross-correlation

I am coding in Matlab, but would be interested to hear suggestions on how this could be implemented in other languages.

Say for example I have a 3D (m,n,t) matrix *M*. I want to run an iterative for loop which will cycle through every *i* (1 : m), and every *j* (1 : n) and then compute the cross-correlation along *t* for the current (*i*, *j*) pair in the loop, with *every* possible (*i*, *j*) combination in the matrix. Hence each (*i*, *j*) has a total of n*m associated correlations.

I have written it out as a kind of pseudocode below but can't think how to implement it properly. Unfortunately in Matlab the 'corrcoef' function doesn't allow you to iterate through 1:m, 1:n within the function itself.

Any help would be great!

```
M = randn(m,n,t);
Xcor_vals = zeros(m,n,m*n);
for i = 1:m 
    for j = 1:n
        R = Xcor(M(i,j,:),M(1:m,1:n,:)); 
        Xcor_vals(i,j,:) = R;
    end
end
```

Comment: so, you have a 2D problem right? the third dimension is unnecessary?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I see your point. I say 3D in the sense that the cross correlation is correlating all information along the third dimension (time series data in my case), but yes for the sake of this problem, I guess it can be thought of as 2D. Thanks.

Comment: mm no, then I missed the point. re-reading now I understand better. If you want to do this "loopy", you need nested 4 for loops. 2 to choose the current `i,j` and another 2 to to go through all other rows/columns not `i,j`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you mean "implemented in other languages"? What language? In matlab i would go for fft first.

```
m=40;n=30;t=100;
M = randn(m,n,t);
Mf = fft(M,[],3);
```

Now you can multiply and ifft to get the cross correlation for all m and n with point i and j.

```
tic
Xcorr_vals = nan(m,n,m,n,t);
for i = 1:m
    for j = 1:n
        Xcorr_vals(i,j,:,:,:) = ifft(conj(Mf(i,j,:)).*Mf,[],3);
    end
end
toc
```

> Elapsed time is 4.24 seconds.

Comment: That's great. Thanks very much!